# Пример по многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность

Поясните, пожалуйста, где я могу быть не прав.

**1.** Главный поток *main* запускает два потока: *t1*, *t2*.

**2.** Поток *main* останавливается и ждет завершения потоков *t1* и *t2* так как вызваны методы *t1.join* и *t2.join*.

**3.** Первый поток *t1* несколько раз засыпает при выполнении, но второй не может начать выполнения метода writing, так как он synchronized. В результате после работы первого потока в файле имеем запись: 
*First0->0 First1->1 First2->2 First3->3 First4->4*

**4.** После окончания первого потока, второй делает тоже самое.

**5.** Два потока завершены, поток main завершает выполнение.

В результате в файле мы можем иметь только запись вида:
First0->0 First1->1 First2->2 First3->3 First4->4 Second0->0 Second1->1 Second2->2 Second3->3 Second4->4 
Но в учебнике приводиться другой результат. Как такое возможно? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by IP44 on 25.11.2016.
 */
class Synchro {
    private FileWriter fileWriter;

    public Synchro(String file) throws IOException {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
    }
    public void close() {
        try {
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void writing(String str, int i) {
        try {
            System.out.print(str + i);
            fileWriter.append(str + i);
            Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 50));
            System.out.print("->" + i + " ");
            fileWriter.append("->" + i + " ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print("Error of stream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Synchro s;

    public MyThread(String str, Synchro s) {
        super(str);
        this.s = s;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            s.writing(getName(), i);
        }
    }
}

public class SynchroThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Synchro s = new Synchro("C:\\Users\\IP44\\Downloads\\data.txt");

            MyThread t1 = new MyThread("First", s);
            MyThread t2 = new MyThread("Second", s);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            s.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в учебнике точно такой код написан?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Только метод `write` помечен как `synchronized`, но не метод `run`, в котором находится цикл. Так что порядок выводв может быть любой. Это можно явно увидеть, если добавить немного ожидания в сам `run` - если бы порядок был задан блокировками, он бы не поменялся.

http://ideone.com/joXG0N

```
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            s.writing(getName(), i);
            Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 50));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
First0->0 
Second0->0 
First1->1 
Second1->1 
First2->2 
Second2->2 
First3->3 
Second3->3 
First4->4 
Second4->4
```

> Но в учебнике приводиться другой результат.

Там не об этом. Там о том, что

```
System.out.print(str + i);
fileWriter.append(str + i);
Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 50)); // <-- В этом месте
System.out.print("->" + i + " ");
fileWriter.append("->" + i + " ");
```

даже несмотря на `sleep` переключения на другой `write` не будет. Т. е. мы никогда не увидим такого:

```
First->Second->0->0
```